# Crystal Reports: How to Identify Usage of a Subreport in Crystal Reports Project?

Tags: crystal-reports, report, subreport, crystal-reports-xi

I'm working on a Crystal Reports project that involves several subreports. Now, I need to track where a specific subreport is being used across different reports.

I've tried to open the file in an IDE so I can search for the filename. Sadly, CR uses a different format that can't be open and in the text-editor just are binaries.

Is there a built-in function of CR that allows me to check this? Do you have suggestions how to check which reports include a particular subreport. Are there any strategies or tools for achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

You can export a Crystal report to a format called 'ReportDefinition'.

Or you can use 3rd-party tools to document, search, and even modify multiple reports. Ken Hamady maintains a listing of such tools [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#doc).

Here is an example of one of these 3rd-party utilities, searching for subreport properties related to whether the subreport reimport path is valid:
[image: Crystal Reports Inspection and Mass-Update Tool]

You can use the Search & Filter dialogs to find all cases where a particular subreport is used within multiple reports.

Comment: Hello @MilletSoftware , we managed to check the list and will download one free tool and test it. Which tool are you using and hat is the price? Can we also check which databases are used by the reports?

Comment: Sorry, can't provide that info here due to forum rules.